# How can I implement facebook login module for hybris

Tags: facebook, authentication, sap-commerce-cloud

How can we implement login module for Hybris with Facebook, instead of asking customer for registration?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all find a jsp solution for [Facebook login](http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/). Then write a [filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.java) and apply this solution. Add filter to spring-filter-config.xml. Implement login as in DefaultAutoLoginStrategy.java. That's all.